# iOS fetching from managed object context before saved

Tags: ios, object, fetch, managed

If I add entities to a moc and I execute a fetch request on that moc before its document gets a chance to save, will my fetch contain the newly added entities? (I'm unsure how to test this out because of the auto-save feature)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're using `UIDocument` when you say 'auto-saving'. If you aren't, then there is no 'auto-saving' (except when using Apple template code and the app delegate saves before termination).

When you create the fetch request, you can choose whether it should include unsaved items using the `includesPendingChanges` property. It defaults to YES so by default you will see unsaved items in the results.